# Output python command result to file

Tags: python

I want to use python as a calculator and output everything into file. But

```
mamboleo@mamboleo-K56CB:~$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 5**555 > output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'output' is not defined
```

It gives me an error, and I couldn't find how to output my result into text file. `2>` does not work either.

Comment: I'm going to close this in favour of this Q&A on stackoverflow which presents two answers for your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728991/writing-python-shell-output-to-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 out = open("output.txt", "w")
 out.write(str(5*5+9))
 out.close()
```

You have to open python file object to do that. If you run python script, then you can use '>':

```
 python test.py > output
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I know this, but thought maybe it's possible without writing a script. Also the text in the file is in single line and I need to scroll horizontally, how do I make output my in normal format to fill my screen?